# Android SU permissions: How to use them?

Tags: java, android, root

There is a situation here, I'm developing an Android application, using Java. I'm pretty familiar with all this stuff, but now it's the first time when I need to use SU permissions. I just need to replace (actually, rename) the file in system/app directory, but it looks like I'm not able to perform it in a usual way (renameTo method in File class), it just returns me FALSE, which means that there was some error in operation.

So can anybody tell me how to use SU? My test phone is fully rooted with SU 3.0.3.2, any app that require SU works perfectly fine.

Shall I use the same method but with some additions in manifest? Shall I use busybox in some way?

I already googled for this, and I can't find any useful information. And also, there is no documentation on official Android Superuser website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295873/how-do-i-request-root-access-in-android

Comment: No problem. A quick search on StackOverflow almost always turns up results ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll probably also need to remount the filesystem as RW since /system is read-only. So you might need to call SU with a similar command below:

`mount -o r,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system`

To execute the command, you can try two ways (I've notice in android sometimes one works and the other won't )

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "mount -o r,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system"});
```

Or you can do

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
p.getOutputStream().write("mount -o r,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system".getBytes());
p.getOutputStream().write(<my next command>);
```

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I need to do it. Sorry for the lame question, but still: how to do it? I mean, how to call SU with some command?

Comment: Edited it a bit to make it more complete.

Comment: Who's awesome? You're awesome! :) I owe you

Comment: @user931366 I think that for multiple commands, you need to put "\n" at the end of each of them. And also put "exit \n" as the last command and also flush the stream.