# Su can be called from adb but not from android

Tags: android, odroid

I am facing an issue on my rooted device (odroid x with my personnal rom)
I have su with userid flag set:

```
root@android:/ # ls -l /system/xbin/su                                         
-rwsr-sr-x root     root        22372 2013-01-02 15:44 su
```

From adb, I can see that the device is rooted :

```
root@android:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
root@android:/ #
```

So for sure perform a su works :)

On the android app, I have a simple Java app requesting su : it does not work.
Using Android terminal, su is failing due to "permission denied"

Notice that I have an other tablet successfully rooted. I put exactly the same rights to su and call to su from android terminal works.

Could you please tell me what I am missing. I read that correct uid must be set to allow android app (having their own user id) to call it. Is it correct ?

Thanks a lot !

Eloi

Comment: @MattClark bzzzt! wrong! The OP is asking how to invoke su from within a android app!

Comment: OP: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295873/how-do-i-request-root-access-in-android), [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295873/how-do-i-request-root-access-in-android)

Comment: OP: your question explicitly states **On the android app, I have a simple Java app requesting su : it does not work** implying/suggesting that you wrote an app?

Comment: it doesn't work because the suid is not set for all. It can be called as root (hence without password) only by root and root group. You need to `chmod a+s` or to change the group and place your app in this group

Comment: More than likely the OP has forgotten to put in a permission in the manifest requesting superuser access?