# how to change port 80 android

Tags: android, webserver, nanohttpd

I made a webserver on my android device(using Nanohttpd). It's working fine over the port 8080
but I want to make it okay over the port 80,(I want to tape on my browser : http://192.168.x.x instead of http://192.168.x.x:8080/ )  but I'm not able to do it

This is how I call the method that creates the webserver:

```
httpServer = new NanoHTTPD(80,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

- Can someone tell me what service is running by default over the port 80 ?
- How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Can you post where you got the library from because the constructor you are using does not seem to be a standard NanoHTTPD constructor. They originally only have `NanoHTTPD(String hostname, int port)` and `NanoHTTPD(int port)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix that, for those who have the same problem, here is the solution

- I rooted the phone using [UnlockRoot](http://www.unlockroot.com/)
- then I installed [Port redirector](http://mawersoft.co.uk/mirror1/webserver/co.uk.mawersoft.ip.tables.apk) from the play store and I forwarded the traffic from port 80 to port 8080, and now my web server is available from the address: 192.168.x.x

Hope it will help :)

Comment: An alternative port redirector on the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bherbst.net&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Ports below 1024 are restricted on Unix like systems. You need superuser privileges to bind to these "well-known" ports.

List of these "well-known" ports on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports)

Comment: if i 'm root, how can i do it

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295873/1321873. After assuming the superuser privileges, you can directly run the webserver on port 80 without the need for port forwarding.

Comment: @Rajest - actually, no, that won't directly work (the post you link is rather misleading).  One would have to use `su` to start the webserver in its own root process, or perhaps have a shim which opens the listening socket and then passes the scoket through a unix domain socket to a non-root web server to use (not sure if that would work)

Answer (score 0):

Check out line 89 of the server source:

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java

I don't even see a constructor that type-matches your arguments. That might be part of the problem.