# Allow Super User permission programmatically

Tags: android, permissions, root, superuser

I want to use shell command for my app as root permission. I put in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
```

I want to know if there is a way to allow Super User permission programmatically without using any input device. As you know a window like this is appearing : [image]

I want to avoid that step and programmatically select Remember choice forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Short answer! You can not do programatically !**

Answer (score 1):

Just exec the command `su` and within that `Process` you have root priviliges:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

See [this blog post](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/) for full example.

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295916/4205927)